# How to change the height of a skewed div tag in a CSS template

Tags: html, css, skew

I'm using a css and html template for a website, this is how the page looks right now- 
[Screenshot of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33HQT.png)

I want to make the height of the blue area smaller, and I can't figure out what to change in the css file. Increasing bottom in fh5co-hero.after from -40 to 100 makes the website look like this- 
[Screenshot after changing the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrdiX.png)

This is the css code-

```
#fh5co-hero {
  background-color: #90d7ea;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center left;
  margin-bottom: 10em;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  color: #ffffff;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #fh5co-hero {
    background-position: center center;
  }
}
#fh5co-hero:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -40px;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100%;
  height: 550px;
  background: #90d7ea;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-3deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(-3deg);
  transform: skewY(-3deg);
  background-color: #90d7ea;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url(../images/hero6.jpg);
}
#fh5co-hero .fh5co-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -70px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -30px;
  display: table;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 24px;
  z-index: 99;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #f86942;
  border-bottom: none !important;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0.125em 0.125em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0.125em 0.125em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0.125em 0.125em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0.125em 0.125em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  box-shadow: 0 0.125em 0.125em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
```

Changing the height values does nothing? 
(Edit) This is the html code-

```
<div id="fh5co-hero">
            <a href="#fh5co-main" class="smoothscroll fh5co-arrow to-animate hero-animate-4"><i class="ti-angle-down"></i></a>
            <!-- End fh5co-arrow -->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="fh5co-hero-wrap">
                        <div class="fh5co-hero-intro">
                            <h1 class="to-animate hero-animate-1">Right Sidebar</h1>
                            <h2 class="to-animate hero-animate-2">This is a right sidebar content</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
```

Comment: works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/2n5985g1/

Comment: When I'm changing the height value in jsfiddle it's working fine, but in safari and chrome there's no change?? whats happening lol

Comment: Maybe the problem is somewhere else, try copying part of code you used here and opening it in web browser... It has to work. If that is the case than the problem is somewhere else not in this div...

Comment: I edited the post to show the html as well, what else could be wrong?

Comment: Now you are missing CSS, upload html and CSS, maybe someone will see some mistake

Comment: Your code works fine, I tried in browser, and in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7p5kouxo/

Comment: That means you made a mistake somewhere in CSS of other elements... you are probabbly missing something like `;` or something bizarre like that